# MSBuild.exe <Exec Command="call test.bat" /> fails with Cannot Find Path Specified

Tags: batch-file, msbuild

I have a .proj file (build.proj) that I'm calling using a .bat (build.bat) file via the command window.

build.bat:

```
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe projects\build.proj /fl1 /flp1:LogFile=build.log;Verbosity=Normal
```

From an elevated command window I run

> **build.bat**

It runs through build.proj all the way up until it tries to call another .bat file.

Here is the line in build.proj where it calls this .bat file (test.bat):

```
<Exec Command="call $(BatchDir)\test.bat />
```

*$(BatchDir) is defined at the top of build.proj and equals "..\batch"*

In the console output I can see that it is trying to call the batch file:
call ..\batch\test.bat
"The system cannot find the path specified"

test.bat definitely exists relative the the projects folder. What am I doing wrong here?

Directory structure:

- /MyProject

  - build.bat
  - /projects

    - build.proj
  - /batch

    - test.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the full path to test.bat in the $(BatchDir) variable.

It looks like it's taking `..` relative to either `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe` or `/MyProject/build.bat`, neither of which have a `..\batch` directory.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct as it is mostly correct. When using <Exec Command="call ... /> the directory it looks in isn't where you'd expect. I still don't know where it is looking but setting the $(BatchDir) variable to be absolute (eg. C:\MyProject\batch) then it works fine. I would still like to get this working using relative directories so if someone can figure that out it'd be great.

Comment: When in doubt, set the Exec Task's WorkingDirectory to `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)`, so you know it's calling the cmd task from the directory that contains the project

Comment: To find out what it's using as `$(BatchDir)`, add the following line to the `<ItemGroup>` before the `<Exec />` line: `<Message Text="BatchDir is: $(BatchDir)" Importance="high" />`